How can I render images in Display P3 color space?
Is it possible make Blender assign the images a proper color space and possibly render in Display P3 (but not HDR)?
Even if I set my sequencer to Display P3, the resulting images are not assigned with a color space. And after some research, the rendered image seem to still be sRGB (but it's just not tagged as such)

